# How to add time to a date-time column, if time is missing

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataframe with a date-time column spaced at 4-hour intervals. When the time component should be `00:00:00` (hour: minute: second), the time is missing from the date. How can I add `00:00:00` to the date when time is missing?

Example Data

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  dateTime = c('2016-07-01',
               '2016-07-01 04:00:00',
               '2016-07-01 08:00:00',
               '2016-07-01 12:00:00',
               '2016-07-01 16:00:00',
               '2016-07-01 20:00:00',
               '2016-07-02')
)

str(dat)
#> 'data.frame':    7 obs. of  1 variable:
#>  $ dateTime: chr  "2016-07-01" "2016-07-01 04:00:00" "2016-07-01 08:00:00" "2016-07-01 12:00:00" ...

dat
#>              dateTime
#> 1          2016-07-01
#> 2 2016-07-01 04:00:00
#> 3 2016-07-01 08:00:00
#> 4 2016-07-01 12:00:00
#> 5 2016-07-01 16:00:00
#> 6 2016-07-01 20:00:00
#> 7          2016-07-02
```

I could use this below however, my real dataset has missing rows, so I am looking for an alternative where I can add `00:00:00` when there is no time.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(dateTime_cor = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2016-07-01 00:00:00"),
                            to = as.POSIXct("2016-07-02 00:00:00"),
                            by = "4 hours")) %>%
  select(-dateTime)

str(dat)
#> 'data.frame':    7 obs. of  1 variable:
#>  $ dateTime_cor: POSIXct, format: "2016-07-01 00:00:00" "2016-07-01 04:00:00" ...

dat
#>          dateTime_cor
#> 1 2016-07-01 00:00:00
#> 2 2016-07-01 04:00:00
#> 3 2016-07-01 08:00:00
#> 4 2016-07-01 12:00:00
#> 5 2016-07-01 16:00:00
#> 6 2016-07-01 20:00:00
#> 7 2016-07-02 00:00:00
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: You can use `lubridate::as_datetime(dateTime)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `lubridate::as_datetime`:

```r
dat |> 
  transform(dateTime = lubridate::as_datetime(dateTime))

#>              dateTime
#> 1 2016-07-01 00:00:00
#> 2 2016-07-01 04:00:00
#> 3 2016-07-01 08:00:00
#> 4 2016-07-01 12:00:00
#> 5 2016-07-01 16:00:00
#> 6 2016-07-01 20:00:00
#> 7 2016-07-02 00:00:00
```